# ScrollMagic/TweenMax, one timeline for multiple scenes/breakpoints

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap, scrollmagic

I have same elements that I need to animate to different parts of page while scrolling (up-down, left-right and so on).
What I did is added scene and timeline for each breakpoint (like #one, #two, ..., #six, etc.) and some movement attached to these sections.
I tried TweenLite.to, then changed it to fromTo.

```
// ONE //
  let elementsTL = new TimelineMax({ paused: true })
  elementsTL.add(
    TweenLite.fromTo('.animation-elements .vertical-line-wrapper', 1.5, {
      top: '2%', ease: Expo.ease,
    }, {
      top: '95%', ease: Expo.ease,
    }),
    0,
  )
  new ScrollMagic.Scene({
    triggerElement: '#one',
    triggerHook: 0.9,
  })
    .setTween(elementsTL)
    .addIndicators({
      name: 'one',
    })
    .addTo(controller)



 // TWO //
  let elements2TL = new TimelineMax({ paused: true })
  elements2TL.add(
    TweenLite.fromTo('.animation-elements .vertical-line-wrapper', 1.5, {
      top: '95%', ease: Expo.ease,
    }, {
      top: '75%', ease: Expo.ease,
    }),
    0,
  )
  new ScrollMagic.Scene({
    triggerElement: '#two',
    triggerHook: 0.9,
  })
    .setTween(elements2TL)
    .addIndicators({
      name: 'two',
    })
    .addTo(controller)
.....
```

the issue is if I scroll fast from last to first, those element jump and I totally understand why. Can I have one timeline that I can attach animations to it and break it to sections (ids)?
What can be done here?

Comment: We at GreenSock don't recommend ScrollMagic. Instead we recommend the official scroll plugin: [ScrollTrigger](https://greensock.com/scrolltrigger/)! It's better in every way.

Comment: @ZachSaucier Thanks for the suggestion, I do like scrollTrigger more, but I have kind of the same problem. I scroll to #a and elements go where I need them, 95% from top, then I sroll further to #b and elements just start from the top (0) and go to 75%, instead of going back to 75 from 95. `gsap.to('.animation-el', { scrollTrigger: { trigger: '#a', start: 'bottom bottom', scrub: 1, toggleActions: 'complete pause reverse pause' }, y: '95%', duration: 2
})
gsap.to('.animation-el', {  scrollTrigger: { trigger: '#b', ... }, y: '75%', ... })`

Comment: Please make a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the ScrollTrigger demo if you'd like help.

Comment: @ZachSaucier https://jsfiddle.net/montyFelix/rbdtqfgw/ it's going from 75% to 0% and then to 95% instead of going straight to 95% from 75%. Can you please check it out?

Comment: I think it'll work out if I change from and to, into fromTo

Comment: I highly recommend reading the [most common ScrollTrigger mistakes](https://greensock.com/st-mistakes/) as you're making at least one of them. I also recommend my article about [animating efficiently](https://css-tricks.com/tips-for-writing-animation-code-efficiently/).